# Windows file PathTooLongException: Batch file to Identify filepaths longer than 255

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, filepath, pathtoolongexception

**Problem**
I have some filepaths exceeding `length=255` that, evidently, cannot be handled (and appear to be disrupting entire operations) during file sync operations on my Windows 7 machine. The exception encountered is [PathTooLongException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception?view=net-5.0)

**Desired Solution:**
I'd like to create a **batch file** that identifies filepaths that exceed 255, and outputs them to a `.txt` file (for diagnostic review)

**UPDATE**
The accepted solution below works perfectly.

*this is my first post here; please be kind*

Comment: Very long path, _(> 256 characters)_, support is turned on by default in RoboCopy, because you 'd need the `/256` option to turn it off. Could you please provide some code and the proper paths so that we can try to reproduce the issue you say you're experiencing.

Comment: I was mistaken in believing robocopy was the origin of the error. I encountered the exception "PathTooLongException
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pathtoolongexception

Comment: Well your question is of no use to us or future readers then. I'd suggest that instead of your poor edit, and removal of bthe [[tag:robocopy]] tag, that you simply delete your question. In its current format, it appears that you're looking for off topic research material, or links, or are making an off topic code request.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback (and noted for future posting). I've revised my question in a way that should be more useful to others (steers attention to the selected answer which contains the code people may be seeking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want just paths (directory paths over 255 chars) or combo filenamr and folder path

Just folders:

```
@(Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  Echo off
  Set "_Root=D:\"
  Set "_ResultFile=D:\PathsOver255Chars.txt"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /B
)

:Main
  For /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
    Dir /B /S /AD "%_Root%*"
  ') DO (
    SET "_CheckLen=%%_"
    IF /I !_CheckLen! NEQ !_CheckLen:~-255! (
      ECHO=%%_>>"%_ResultFile%"
    )
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Just files:

```
@(Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  Echo off
  Set "_Root=D:\"
  Set "_ResultFile=D:\PathsOver255Chars.txt"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /B
)

:Main
  For /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
    Dir /B /S /A-D-S-H "%_Root%*"
  ') DO (
    SET "_CheckLen=%%_"
    IF /I !_CheckLen! NEQ !_CheckLen:~-255! (
      ECHO=%%_>>"%_ResultFile%"
    )
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Folders and files

```
@(Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  Echo off
  Set "_Root=D:\"
  Set "_ResultFile=D:\PathsOver255Chars.txt"
)

CALL :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /B
)

:Main
  For /F "Tokens=*" %%_ IN ('
    Dir /B /S  "%_Root%*"
  ') DO (
    SET "_CheckLen=%%_"
    IF /I !_CheckLen! NEQ !_CheckLen:~-255! (
      ECHO=%%_>>"%_ResultFile%"
    )
  )
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: This is an impressive answer, thank you. Identifying filepath+filename > 255 is goal, though for the output just identifying the corresponding folders is adequate (my intent is to manually review the list of especially long filepaths. Output to text file is ideal, thank you.

Comment: I have 13 and need 15 :/  It lets me vote internally, though, so you get the algorithmic boost at some level -- just doesn't yet permit me to affect the votes shown yet.

Comment: @derekclark ahh gotcha, I think it was 10 when I joined, or maybe I am missremembering, perhaps that was commenting that started at 10.  Thanks for the upvote either way.  Also it looks like you don't get comment upvotes added to you at this level of points perhaps as I upvoted that comment and your points didn't change, so I guess next time you ask/answer a Q it'll shake itself out.

Comment: I finally have the reputation to validate your answer :) And I can also add that the code successfully identified about 500 filepaths, all of which could be resolved via a handful of moves (mounts)

Answer (score 0):

This solution does not test it particularly for 255+ characters, but still tests in a long path specifically in a script inside cmd.exe.

*Seems the stackoverflow incorrectly handles tabulation characters (and loses other characters like `\x01` or `\x04`) in the copy-pasted code, so the below code might not work if you copy it directly by CTRL+C. Even the `View Page Source` does not show not printable characters. So to fix type `ALT+0,4` after all `eol=` in all for loops.*

**Pros**:

- no need to check a path length

**Cons**:

- a path must be an existed path

```
@echo off

setlocal

set "FILE_PATH=%~1"

if not defined FILE_PATH exit /b 1

for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%i in ("%FILE_PATH%\.") do ^
for /F "eol= tokens=* delims=" %%j in ("%%~dpi.") do ( set "FILE_PATH=%%~fi" & set "FILE_DIR=%%~fj" )

if "%FILE_PATH:~0,4%" == "\\?\" set "FILE_PATH=%FILE_PATH:~4%"

echo "FILE_PATH=%FILE_PATH%"

rem for a path
if exist "\\?\%FILE_PATH%" if exist "%FILE_PATH%" ( echo.* a short path) else echo.a long path

rem for a file path
if exist "\\?\%FILE_PATH%" if not exist "\\?\%FILE_PATH%\*" if exist "%FILE_PATH%" ( echo.* a short file path) else echo.a long file path

rem for a directory path
if exist "\\?\%FILE_PATH%\*" if exist "%FILE_PATH%" ( echo.* a short directory path) else echo.a long directory path
```